# python geoalchemy2 error when creating a table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis

iam working on a project that uses geographical points.
From the past i have some knowledge with sqlalchemy so i decided to use geoalchmy2.

I created a postgres database with GIS using a docker image:
https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/

For the first test i use a simple model from the example page of geoalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@localhost/Test', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()
class Lake(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lake'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    data = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid=5312))

Lake.__table__.create(engine)
```

if i run the program i recieve an error:
**sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) type "geometry" does not exist**

i spend now 3 days on that topic an read whatever i can find but found no solution.

Comment: i figured out that the Problem ist from the Postgres Server.
The server did not understand the geometry type.

I tested it by hand via pgadmin und the printed SQL Command from the echo on the console

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need PostGIS installed as an extension in your database. Simply connect to your database server through your pgsql shell.

```
psql
```

Connect to your database - in this case the "Test" database.

```
\c Test user
```

Then install the extension as the user who owns that particular database.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

When you log out, you'll be able to access the geometry types.

**NOTE:**
You will need privileges to enable extensions with the particular user that owns the database. For the purposes of testing, you can make that Test user a superuser. DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION.

```
ALTER USER Test WITH SUPERUSER;
```

In production, you should practice the least-privilege principle and only give your user the minimum amount of privileges necessary to operate your app. This means restricting superuser to an account that is not in use by your app and (preferably) can only be accessed through localhost.